# Запуск события jquery после смены параметров стиля

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace

У меня есть блок, которого меняется прозрачность и позиция(top, left). По сути этот блок отображает курсор в поле.

```
<div class="ace_cursor" style="top: 10; left: 15; opacity: 0.2;">
```

Как и какое запускать событие, когда меняется **top** и/или **left**?

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос

Comment: Какое событие использовать, после того как меняется конкретный параметр стиля у элемента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такого события нету, но вы можете его создать вручную.

Регистрируем событие:

```
$('.ace_cursor').bind('css-changed',function(){...});
```

В коде, где вы изменяете сам `css` добавляете строчку

```
$('.ace_cursor').trigger('css-changed');
```

Которая в свою очередь тригернет событие `css-changed`